# CSS: Overlaping two images and proper flow

Tags: html, css, overlap, overlapping

As you can see in http://jsfiddle.net/omarjuvera/v93us4n9/6/ the paragraph is not where it should be, since I am overlapping two images. How can I fix this?

**HTML**

```
<h1>Overlaping two images</h1>
<div>
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/brMyE7To7Sg/0.jpg" />
    <img src="http://oi57.tinypic.com/2u8kr2s.jpg" />
</div>
<br/>

<p>For some reason, this paragraph is not below DIV, but under/over</p>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    position: relative;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because both of the `img` elements are absolutely positioned and removed from the flow.

Due to this, the parent `div` element collapses upon itself and has a height of `0`. Unless the parent `div` element has explicit dimensions, in this case a height, the text will overlap.

Setting an explicit height on the parent element will solve this, but that's not a very flexible solution.

In your case, since the `img` elements are the same size, you could solve this by only absolutely positioning a single `img` element. In doing so, the height of the parent `div` element will be defined based on the height of the `img` element that isn't absolutely positioned.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/10stbdfq/)

```
<div>
    <img src="//placehold.it/480x360" />
    <img class="overlay" src="http://oi57.tinypic.com/2u8kr2s.jpg" />
</div>
```

```
div {
    position: relative;
}
img.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Clever! I didn't wanna add an "absolute" size for proper RWD. Thanks